# Foreach to combine to array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have these arrays in the beggining:

```
Array
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 8
            [4] => 4
        )

    [qtys] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 22
            [2] => 100
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
        )

)
```

I when to combine these arrays in order to have this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 5
            [qty] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 20
            [qty] => 22
        ) ...
```

But with this foreach :

```
$products = $post['products'];
            $qtys = $post['qtys'];

            $array = [];


            foreach($products as $product){
                foreach($qtys as $quantity){

                    if(!in_array($product, $array)){
                    $array[] = array(
                            'product_id' => $product,
                            'qty' => $quantity
                        );
                    }
                }
            }

            echo "<pre>".print_r($array, true)."</pre>";
```

I have this result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 5
            [qty] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 5
            [qty] => 22
        )
```

I tried many this, for example with break, continue.
I even tried array_combine, the result wasn't what I expected. 
I thought about using array_unique, but is not working with multidimensional arrays (that's what I understood).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your original `$post` array and use one simple `foreach` using the key:

```
foreach($post['products'] as $key => $value){
    $array[] = array('product_id' => $value,
                     'qty' => $post['qtys'][$key]
               );
}
```

If you want to avoid duplicate products as it seems from your `!in_array`, then just key the result by the `product_id`:

```
foreach($post['products'] as $key => $value){
    $array[$value] = array('product_id' => $value,
                           'qty' => $post['qtys'][$key]
                     );
}
```

If needed you can re-index with `$array = array_values($array);`.

Comment: Yes, I thought I needed to avoid duplicate, but finaly I don't have to. So the first solution is the right one. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As your keys are numerical and continous starting from 0:

```
// $post is your array with all the data
$newArray = [];
for ($i=0; $i < count($post['products']); $i++) { 
    $newArray[] = [
        'product_id' => $post['products'][$i];
        'qty' => $post['qtys'][$i];
    ];
}
```

Also I'm assuming that the ´products´ and ´qtys´ arrays are the same length.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using two nested loops, so all the items in your first `array` will be paired with all items in your second array. Instead you will need to loop by index and add items.

```
function mergeProductQuantities($products, $quantities) {
    //Creating an empty output array
    $output = array();
    //Getting the number of iterations
    $limit = ($pc = count($products)) > ($qc = count($quantities)) ? $pc : $qc;
    //Doing the actual iteration
    for ($index = 0; $index < $limit; $index++) {
        //Creating a new item
        $newItem = array();
        //Setting applicable values
        if (isset($products[$index])) $newItem["product_id"] = $products[$index];
        if (isset($quantities[$index])) $newItem["qty"] = $quantities[$index];
        //Adding the new item to the output
        $output[]=$newItem;
    }
    return $output;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
$result = mergeProductQuantities($post['products'], $post['qtys']);
```